# REST: Using PUT to update with a file upload

Tags: php, api, rest, multipartform-data, put

I'm coding an API and got stuck on the UPDATE part of things. From what I've read about REST the update operation should be exposed by using HTTP PUT.

Ok, PUT gives me just a stream of data. At least in PHP the decoding of this data is my responsibility. So how do I mix string data and file upload and use PUT? I know I can do it in POST but I'm trying to do it the RESTful way.

Should I use multipart/form-data and is that portable for PUT (I mean is it easy to send this kind of request in different languages)? I'm trying to figure out the `proper` way to do this. Again, if I use multipart/form-data I'm responsible for the parsing so there might be some errors or performance degradation. Can you suggest a parser if this multipart/... is the way to do what I'm asking?

Thanks

Comment: So the goal is to save data from a client into a file on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General rule of PUT is that is idempotent

Calling 2x `PUT /user/{userId}/files/foo.txt` ends up in the same state, with the 2nd call you would simply override the foo.txt. You are 'setting' things.

Calling 2x `POST /user/{userId}/files` would end up in two different files. You are 'adding' things.

Therefore I would use PUT if you want to write to a dedicated target. What kind of files do you want to upload. E.g. if it is a picture-upload I would use POST (where you would get the target url inside response). If you are designing a kind of file-storage for a user I would use PUT, because most likely users want to write (set) to a certain location (like you would on a ordinary file-system).

Maybe you have more details/requirements for a concrete case?

Comment: I decided to go with POST. The problem was along with the file I need to give it other information such as Title, description etc.

Comment: But PUT doesn't exclude this. You can pass the same payload with PUT as you would do with POST. The Content-Type of your Request is orthogonal to your HTTP method.

Comment: I know but it didn't feel natural to me. Also with PHP I would need to manually parse the data which it does with POST automatically

Comment: I know, that one can get "stuck" too much onto POST (especially when one is coming from the SOAP side). But when you did the restful think-switch of uniform interface, the usage of the single HTTP methods (PUT/DELETE/GET/POST) feel very natural.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of data are you attempting to `PUT`? Remember that PUT is a directed publishing method. The client sends data to the server and essentially says "`PUT` this file into /home/sites/.../myfile.txt".

Useful for when you're publishing data to a site and are creating a new page. Not so useful if it's a standard file upload form ("Upload an avatar image here!"). You don't want to allow potentially malicious users to specify where an uploaded file should go.

That's when you use POST, which translates into "here's a file, it's called myfile.txt, do what you want with it".

Comment: Then what's the point in using `PUT` in REST? Should I just ignore it and use `POST` to update, too?

Comment: PUT is highly targeted, POST is more general purpose. Each has its place, but in general POST is probably the easiest to deal with it.